# print from android device on a windows shared printer

Tags: java, android, smb, jcifs

I have to print via Windows Shared Printer on Android. I use the below code using jcifs-1.3.19.jar.

```
 private void doSmbPrinting() {
    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        NtlmPasswordAuthentication authentication = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", "username", "password");

        SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile("smb://username:password@10.0.0.53/SHARENAME/Untitled", authentication);
        SmbFileOutputStream uncOut = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile); // Exception is in this line
        PrintWriter uncPrint = new PrintWriter(uncOut);
        uncPrint.println("print text ");
        uncPrint.flush();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**I am getting below error:**

> 12-21 14:19:13.729 26993-26993/com.abdu.sampleandroid W/System.err: jcifs.smb.SmbException: The parameter is incorrect.
>           at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:563)
>           at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:663)
>        12-21 14:19:13.730 26993-26993/com.abdu.sampleandroid W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
>           at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
>           at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:775)
>           at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:992)
>           at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:1009)
>        12-21 14:19:13.731 26993-26993/com.abdu.sampleandroid W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.(SmbFileOutputStream.java:142)
>           at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.(SmbFileOutputStream.java:97)
>           at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.(SmbFileOutputStream.java:67)
>           at com.abdu.sampleandroid.MainActivity.doSmbPrinting(MainActivity.java:59)
>           at com.abdu.sampleandroid.MainActivity.doPrint(MainActivity.java:47)
>           at com.abdu.sampleandroid.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:41)

Please help me on the issue. I am able to add the shared printer in Mac with the same smb url, and made prints. Its working(only frustration is its asking credentials every time). How can we make a print from the Android device on a windows shared printer?

**UPDATE**

with above code i can write to a file in shared folder. only change is

```
 SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile("smb://username:password@10.0.0.53/FOLDERNAME/file.txt", authentication);
```

This also works, no need to give username and password in URL. Since there is NtlmPasswordAuthentication

```
 SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile("smb://10.0.0.53/FOLDERNAME/file.txt", authentication);
```

So I doubt this code is to write a file in shared folder(OR writing on to printer is ok). If that is the case how we make a print using jcifs.smb?

Comment: post your correct error log.

Comment: this is what the exception prints. how I get correct error log